# Tavern - can't post files using aws pre-signed url

Tags: post, multipartform-data, pre-signed-url, tavern

I'm new to Tavern and I'm implementing tests for an AWS API Gateway application.

#### Case Description and Normal Approach

In my case, I use pre-signed URLs to directly upload files to S3 bucket. A pre-signed URL is formed by the following attributes:

```py
url = 'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/' 

fields:
  key=<filename>.zip 
  x-amz-algorithm=*** 
  x-amz-credential=***  
  x-amz-date=*** 
  x-amz-security-token=*** 
  policy=*** 
  x-amz-signature=***
```

In a normal cURL request, this would be used as follows:

```sh
curl -v \
-F key=<filename>.zip \
-F x-amz-algorithm=*** \
-F x-amz-credential=*** \
-F x-amz-date=*** \
-F x-amz-security-token=*** \
-F policy=*** \
-F x-amz-signature=*** \
-F file=@<filename>.zip \
'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

#### Implemented Test

As you can see, it's necessary to use the `-F` flag of `cURL` which forms a `multipart/form-data` POST request.

In `Tavern` approach, and as I read, `-F` is equivalent to `files`, so this would be as follows:

```
stages:
  - name: UPLOAD A FILE TO S3
    request:
      method: POST
      url: "https:/<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/"
      files: 
          key: target.zip 
          x-amz-algorithm: ***
          x-amz-credential: *** 
          x-amz-date: ***
          x-amz-security-token: *** 
          policy: *** 
          x-amz-signature: ***
          file: '@target.zip'
    response:
      status_code: 200
```

#### Error

But it's failing with the error :

```
Error: <value of x-amz-algorithm> file not found
```

So it's considering the fields as files and so it fails.

Is it possible to have this case implemented in `Tavern` and so my implementation is wrong somewhere, or this is not possible in `Tavern` yet?

Kind regards,

Rshad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stages:
  - name: UPLOAD A FILE TO S3
    request:
      method: POST
      url: "https:/<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/"
      data: 
          key: target.zip 
          x-amz-algorithm: ***
          x-amz-credential: *** 
          x-amz-date: ***
          x-amz-security-token: *** 
          policy: *** 
          x-amz-signature: ***
      files:
          file: "target.zip"
    response:
      status_code: 200
```

Comment: Hi my friend @Ashaman! I swear I tested this solution, but it didn't work this morning, neither now. But I then thought that maybe the presigned URL is not valid anymore, because it expires after 3 hours and then trying with a new presigned-url it does work. Thanks a lot!